# HTTP Got Response Error 400

Tags: php, paypal

> PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

My code for `payment.php`:

```
<?php

    $base = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    require_once $base.'/gsys3/assets/php/paypal.api.php';

    use PayPal\Api\Payer;
    use PayPal\Api\Details;
    use PayPal\Api\Amount;
    use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
    use PayPal\Api\Payment;
    use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['account'])){
        header('Location: ../../main.php');
    } elseif($_SESSION['account']['perms'] != 3){
        header('Location: ../../main.php');
    }

    $payer          = new Payer();
    $details        = new Details();
    $amount         = new Amount();
    $transaction    = new Transaction();
    $payment        = new Payment();
    $redirectUrls   = new RedirectUrls();

    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $shippingcost           = '1';
    $taxcost                = '7';
    $subtotalcost           = '100';
    $totalcost              = $shippingcost + $taxcost + $subtotalcost;

    $details->setShipping($shippingcost)
            ->setTax($taxcost)
            ->setSubtotal($subtotalcost);

    $amount->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($totalcost)
            ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                ->setDescription('Enrollment');

    $payment->setIntent('sale')
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost:8080/gsys3/public/dashboard/parent/pay.php?approved=true')
                 ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost:8080/gsys3/public/dashboard/parent/pay.php?approved=false');

    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

    try {
        $payment->create($paypalapi);
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $pce){
        echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode($pce->getData()));exit;
    }
```

My `paypal.api.php`:

```
<?php
    # Start the session
    session_name('_session');
    session_start();

    # This is the connection credentials to the database! Please edit with caution
    $db_host       = '127.0.0.1';
    $db_database   = 'thegrades';
    $db_username   = 'root';
    $db_password   = '';

    # Initialize the connection to the database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_database}", $db_username, $db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $base = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    require_once $base.'/gsys3/vendor/autoload.php';

    use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
    use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

    $paypalapi          = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            '{confidential}',
            '{confidential}'
        )
    );

    $paypalapi->setConfig([
        'mode'                      => 'sandbox',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut'    => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled'            => false,
        'log.FileName'              => '',
        'log.LogLevel'              => 'FINE',
        'validation.level'          => 'log'
    ]);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['account'])){
        header('Location: ../../main.php');
    } elseif($_SESSION['account']['perms'] != 3){
        header('Location: ../../main.php');
    }
```

I've checked the client and secret keys which is accurate

Comment: Have you checked the [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/errors/#validation-errors)?

Comment: @Pyromonk Yeah, I've checked it out and I _think_ I've put the right params.

Comment: If it's returning a 400, then one of those parameters is most likely off. I would recommend echoing them (unless there's a security risk involved).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you activate the log for to get more information about exceptions. These are my settings for develop.

```
    $apiContext->setConfig(
        array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG',
        )
    );
```